# How do I start a EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL node in ZooKeeper at a certain number?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Normally a EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL node in zookeeper starts at 1, is there a way to make it start at a particular number for example 1,000,000 ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. 
Zookeeper is handling the consistency of the data: it guarantees that two nodes created concurrently will not be given the same number. So, Zookeeper needs to stay in control of those numbers. Here you can find information about consistency in Zookeeper: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.2.1/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkGuarantees